Copy a formula to a new row of the same sheet
I have a google sheet where records arrive from a google form.
Is it possible to make it so that for each new row created (from the form) you can paste the formulas present in the row above?
I attach an image of the sheet
enter image description here
In column F2, I would like there to be an ARRAYFORMULA that allows me to copy a formula for all the new rows below (F3, F4, F5, ETC..)
In F3 (and so on) there must be a formula that calculates the difference in days from today, from the birthday date in E3.
In F4, the difference in days from today, from the birthday date in E4
In F5 .... E5
I tried this formula but it returns a value (249) and not the formula that calculates the correct days.

=arrayformula(if(len(A4:A), datedif(E4:E, today(), "YD"), iferror(ø)) )

Thanks everyone.

Why not use an Arrayformula/Lambda function to deal with the formulas of the succeeding rows and then only use the script to plug in the input data?

@PatrickdC Unfortunately I am not an expert in programming language. I really don't know how to do it.
With Arrayformula/Lambda function then the sheet automatically updates for each row created?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, provide a minimal, reproducible example using Tables or tools like Table to Markdown that can easily be copied and pasted. If necessary, and as a last resort, Make an anonymous sample document.

By the way, @PatrickdC's comment to use an Arrayformula/Lambda function is a simpler way to achieve your goal to paste the formulas in each new row created. For example, in D2 you may put =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="", "", "www.link.it")) or =BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(a, IF(a="", "", "www.link.it"))), which puts www.link.it whenever there's data in Column A that came from the form. Kindly Edit the question showing your data as a markdown table and the formulas that you're using for the community to be able to help you.

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

It is not always helpful to show the current formula that fails to get the results you want. Instead, use should show your data and the desired results you'd like to get from that data. [Edit] the question and add tables.


The correct thing is that:
on column F5 it put the formula: =DATA.DIFF(E5; TODAY(); "YD");

Array formulas return multiple values automatically and do not need to be copied down.
Use datedif(). Put this formula in cell F2:
=arrayformula( 
  if(len(E2:E), datedif(E2:E, today(), "YD"), iferror(ø)) 
)

See datedif().

Thanks.
In Italian this is the correct formula
'=ARRAYFORMULA(SE(LUNGHEZZA(A4:A); DATA.DIFF(E3; OGGI(); "YD"); SE.ERRORE("")))'
and now it doesn't give an error but it returns the value (249) but not the formula :-(
The correct thing is that on column F5 it put the formula:
'=DATA.DIFF(E5; OGGI(); "YD");'
On column F6:
=DATA.DIFF(E6; OGGI(); "YD");
etc...

Edited the answer to use E4:E instead of the fixed E3 that was specified in the question. Array formulas return multiple values automatically and do not need to be copied down. Edit the question and add all relevant detail there. Observe TheMaster's comment.

The goal is to calculates the difference in days from today to the birthday date in E3, E4, etc., disregarding the year dates in the cells, and assume that they're for the current year (e.g., 2024).
You may also try this in F2:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E="", "", TEXT(TODAY(), "MM/DD")-TEXT(E2:E, "MM/DD")))

I've noticed that DATEDIF only calculates leap years if the year provided in E2:E is one, so for 02/06/1977, since 2024's a leap year, it returns 311 instead of 312. This is a minor issue of a day unless you need the output to be specific.

Note: Similar to @doubleunary's answer, you don't need to drag the formula down since the IF function within the ARRAYFORMULA checks if there's a date in Column E, ensuring that it only calculates the difference for valid birthday dates.

OUTPUT



Column E
TEXT & MINUS
DATEDIF




08/04/1974
132
132


02/06/1977
312
311


01/08/1984
341
341


01/11/1999
338
337


02/29/2000
289
289



REFERENCE

TEXT
MINUS function


First of all thank you very much
I had to adapt the formula in Italian.
'=ARRAYFORMULA(SE(E2:E=""; ""; TESTO(OGGI(); "MM/DD")-TESTO(E2:E; "MM/DD")))'
But it gives me this error:
Error
Parameter 1 of the MINUS function expects number values, but "12/13" is text and cannot be interpreted as a number.

Can you share if that's on one of the outputs in E3:E or all of them?

If it's only happening to one of the cells, try changing 12/13 to something like 12/13/2024.

If the spreadsheet uses an international locale like Italy you probably need to use d/M instead of MM/DD. But it probably makes more sense to use datedif(). Edit the question and add a table of sample data and another one with desired results.

My bad, I'm not very familiar with international locales, so thank you for that, @doubleunary. Using DATEDIF() is actually a much simpler approach; my answer is just an alternative to inform the OP of what I've observed.

Great, everything works perfectly now.
Thanks everyone for your precious help.

That's wonderful! Please feel free to accept either mine or @doubleunary's answer, as this will confirm that the issue has been resolved. You may also review, What should I do when someone answers my question? for more information.
